# NumPy: create bool array like "repeat" but in multiple dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I'm looking for sort of the opposite of `sum()` I guess.  Here we go:

```
x = array([
    [False, False, False, False, False],
    [ True, False, False, False, False],
    [ True,  True, False, False, False],
    [ True,  True,  True, False, False]])

x.sum(axis=1)
Out: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

So I want to go the opposite direction: from `[0,1,2,3]` to an array like `x` (I can specify the number of columns I want in x, of course, above it's 5).

The solution should ideally work for higher dimensions too, and I don't want to loop in Python of course, because the input could be longer than this example.  That said, here's a solution using a loop:

```
s = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
y = np.zeros((len(s), 5), np.bool)
for row,col in enumerate(s):
    y[row,0:col] = True
```

Comment: Looks like you are thinking about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310346/fast-way-to-perform-complex-operations-on-large-numpy-arrays :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: correct!  I know how to get from here to there...but got a little stuck here.

Comment: In your loop solution, it looks like the *input* is `x`, and you create `y`, but earlier you say to want to go from [0, 1, 2, 3] *to* `x` (i.e. `x` is the output).  Isn't the operation from [0,1,2,3] to the bigger boolean array what you want?

Comment: If so, you can do something like I did in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26269893/numpy-increment-elements-of-an-array-given-the-indices-required-to-increment/26277670#26277670, but change the equality in the comparison to `arange(A.max()+1)` to `<` (as in @DSM's answer).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: yeah, the loop code I put in the question was a bit confusing so I updated it to hopefully make it more clear/self-contained/non-self-referential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC -- and I'm not sure that I do -- you could use `arange` and a broadcasting comparison:

```
>>> v = np.array([0,1,3,2])
>>> np.arange(5) < v[...,None]
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

or in 2D:

```
>>> v = np.array([[1,2],[0,2]])
>>> np.arange(5) < v[...,None]
array([[[ True, False, False, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False, False, False]],

       [[False, False, False, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False, False, False]]], dtype=bool)
>>> ((np.arange(5) < v[...,None]).sum(2) == v).all()
True
```

Comment: You sure did understand--even before I clarified my example.  Thank you, I would not have thought of this solution.